# Como publicar status na timeline do usuário no facebook?

Tags: java, facebook, oauth

Fiz um app no *facebook* e peguei o `app_secret` enfim peguei tudo, o objetivo é que o usuário publique na sua própria linha do tempo entretanto, eu consigo até publicar mas só no meu app e com o login do app, quando executo a aplicação com outro usuário até loga mas não posta a msg, estou usando o facebook4j, a pergunta é existe alguma configuração para fazer na `graph api` além do padrão ou eu tenho que mudar o código abaixo?

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId("MEU ID", "MEU APP_SECRET");
    try {

        facebook.getOAuthAccessToken("O MEU TOKEN DA APLICAÇÃO");

    } catch (FacebookException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    facebook.setOAuthPermissions("email,publish_actions");          
    ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    confBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
    confBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

    confBuilder.build();

    request.getSession().setAttribute("facebook", facebook);

    StringBuffer callbackURL = request.getRequestURL();
    int index = callbackURL.lastIndexOf("/");
    callbackURL.replace(index, callbackURL.length(), "").append("/callback");
    response.sendRedirect(facebook.getOAuthAuthorizationURL(callbackURL.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Oi, Marcos, bem vindo ao site. Por favor, tente formatar a pergunta corretamente e dar um título descritivo. Pode [edit] para corrigir coisas (link bem abaixo das tags).